# get the content from one special character to another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="abc" onclick="location.href='/new-data/?asd=asd'">
</div>
```

The output I require is `new-data` in `location.href`.
How will I do it using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Is there any specific issue you are facing running your _js_ code??

Comment: i think he means he needs the content between the "/"'s this is just an assumption though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, since div id is "abc" and value of onclick has always the form of

`whatever/somedata/whatever`

```
function GetTheContentFromOneSpecialCharacterToAnotherOne()
{
    var the_full_content = document.getElementById('abc').getAttribute('onclick');

    var the_parts = the_full_content.split('/');

    return the_parts[1];
}
```